# python how to register dynamic class in module

Tags: python, class, module, metaprogramming

I have module foo, inside this module I dynamically created class:

```
def superClassCreator():
    return type("Bar", (object,), {})
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to make this new dynamic class visible as a class of this module:

```
import foo
dir(foo)
>>> [... 'Bar' ...]
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `Bar = superClassCreator()` in `foo` (at the module level).

Alternatively, from another module, you can add `Bar` as an attribute on `foo`:

```
import foo

foo.Bar = superClassCreator()
```

or, if the name must be taken from the generated class:

```
import foo

generatedClass = superClassCreator()
setattr(foo, generatedClass.__name__, generatedClass)
```

From within the `foo` module, you can set it directly on `globals()`:

```
generatedClass = superClassCreator()
globals()[generatedClass.__name__] = generatedClass
del generatedClass
```

with an optional `del` statement to remove the `generatedClass` name from the namespace again.

Comment: What if the name is generated dynamically? You can't do this in that case.

Comment: When I print generatedClass.__module__ I see it's different then foo. Actually I would like to put it in that module and not in foo. Should I write setattr(generatedClass.__module__, generatedClass.__name__, generatedClass) in that case?

Comment: @mnowotka: That would not work, you'd need to look up the module in `sys.modules`. Use `setattr(sys.modules[generatedClass.__module__], generatedClass.__name__, generatedClass)`. Note that `__module__` is going to be the module in which `superClassCreator()` is defined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thats strange because it looks like generatedClass.__module__ is a module where the base class is defined. superClassCreator is defined in foo and as i said generatedClass.__module__ is different then that.

Comment: @mnowotka: I don't see that behaviour at all. The module set on the result of `type()` appears to be the current module in my tests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
check in python manage.py shell:
>>> from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
>>> new = type("Bar", (ModelResource, ), {})
>>> new.__module__
'tastypie.resources'

Comment: @mnowotka: what python version? I did the same test (albeit with a different module) in python 2.7 and got `__main__`. Same in Python 2.6.

Comment: I'd say the Django shell is mucking something up, yes. `import unittest`, `type('Bar', (unittest.TestCase,), {}).__module__` gives me `__main__` in all python versions that I've tried this with.

Comment: Good to know, in that case I will explicitly provide desired module name.

Comment: @mnowotka: you can *set* the `__module__` attribute, btw. You can also provide a `__module__` key in the `dict` argument to `type()`. So `type('Bar', (object,), {'__module__': 'foo.baz'})`. I've verified the C source of `type()`, it takes `__name__` from the current globals. So it's your Django shell mucking about.